# Problems deploying to IBM Cloud

Tags: tensorflow, ibm-cloud, tensorflow.js

I created a web app in NodeJS which uses Tensorflow to get a prediction from a model trained in Python. What I'm trying to do is deploy that through IBM Cloud's Cloud Foundry SDK for NodeJS. The problem I'm running into is when I'm trying to push my project to IBM Cloud. From looking at the logs in the console it seems that TensorflowJS Node when it's installing and runs

> node-gyp rebuild

it causes some issues. For some reason it runs into an error when that's running which is

> /temp/app/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/deps/tensorflow/lib/libtensorflow.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

and from there it causes a long chain of errors. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is are the command line logs.

```
Downloaded build artifacts cache (484.1K)
Staging...
-----> IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v3.21-20180628-1258
      Based on Cloud Foundry Node.js Buildpack v1.5.24
-----> Creating runtime environment

      NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
      NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
      NODE_ENV=production
      NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
      engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
      engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

      Resolving node version (latest stable) via 'node-version-resolver'
      Installing IBM SDK for Node.js (6.14.3) from cache
      Using default npm version: 3.10.10
-----> Restoring cache
      Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
      - node_modules (exists - skipping)
      - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Checking and configuring service extensions before installing 
dependencies
-----> Building dependencies
      Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
      Rebuilding any native modules

      > protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/protobufjs
      > node scripts/postinstall


      > @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.9 install 
/tmp/app/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
      > node-gyp rebuild

      make: Entering directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs- 
node/build'
      ACTION binding_gyp_tfjs_binding_target_download_libtensorflow 
Release/libtensorflow.so
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/tfjs_binding/binding/tfe_utils.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/tfjs_binding/binding/tfjs_backend.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/tfjs_binding/binding/tfjs_binding.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/tfjs_binding.node
      /tmp/app/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs- 
node/deps/tensorflow/lib/libtensorflow.so: file not recognized: File 
format 
not recognized
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      make: *** [Release/obj.target/tfjs_binding.node] Error 1
      make: Leaving directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs- 
node/build'
      gyp ERR! build error
      gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
      gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/tmp/app/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
      gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
      gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
      gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:219:12)
      gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
      gyp ERR! command "/tmp/app/vendor/node/bin/node" 
"/tmp/app/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/bin/node- gyp.js" "rebuild"
      gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/app/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
      gyp ERR! node -v v6.14.3
      gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
      gyp ERR! not ok

      npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
      npm ERR!
      npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.9 install script 
'node-gyp rebuild'.
      npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
installed.
      npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
      npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
      npm ERR! argv "/tmp/app/vendor/node/bin/node" 
"/tmp/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild" "-- 
nodedir=/tmp/app/vendor/node"
      npm ERR! node v6.14.3
      npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
      npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
      npm ERR! Exit status 1
      npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the 
@tensorflow/tfjs-node package,
      npm ERR! not with npm itself.
      npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
      npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this 
project with:
      npm ERR!     npm bugs @tensorflow/tfjs-node
      npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
      npm ERR!     npm owner ls @tensorflow/tfjs-node
      npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

      npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support 
request:
      npm ERR!     /tmp/app/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed

      Some possible problems:

      - node_modules checked into source control
      http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html

      - Node version not specified in package.json
      http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html

Failed to compile droplet: Failed to compile droplet: exit status 1
Exit status 223
Staging failed: STG: Exited with status 223
Stopping instance 4e1dd2ee-71b4-4f84-95e8-c5f6c7bd24e0
Destroying container
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile 
phase
FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason if I remove the node_modules folder from the working directory and then try to push to IBM Cloud it works. My guess is probably because when Tensorflow installs it installs certain files depending on your operating system and in my case

> libtensorflow.so

was one of those files.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem related to the version of NodeJs installed on your cloud environment. The errors shows that the version of NodeJs being used is `Node.js (6.14.3)` whereas tensorflowJs requires **Node V8+**

Comment: OH. I didn't think about that. I specified it in the package.json and thought that would do it. I think it's because of the NodeJS version of the buildpack I'm using. Let me see what happens when I switch it out.

Comment: Yes, definitely I do think that it is the root cause of the issue. Let me know what is the result after making the change.

Comment: Hm. I changed buildpack and made sure the NodeJS version was greater then 8. I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Bootsie123 You have to delete the node modules folder and try to reinstall the packages again otherwise the old modules will still be used and that will cause your install to fail